# How to open a outlook 2007-addin project with a button click in a different windows form project

Tags: c#, winforms

My solution contains two projects, one is a Windows form and the second is a 
Outlook 2007 Add-in project.

I have added one form, to the form project, and it contains one button. When clicking the button, I would like it to open the Outlook 2007 Add-in project.

And then I will perform operations on the Outlook 2007 Add-in project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The add-in project can be just use in outlook.

You can open outlook to use this

```
Process.Start("outlook.exe");
```

Comment: i want to open proj outlook 2007 Addin calling the object ThisAddIn class

Comment: Why not create an new project librairies and use this in your 2 project for common code?

Comment: i created but when i create object of class  ThisAddIn in another project requires two paramater 1.:Microsoft.Office.Tools.Outlook.Factory factory 2. System.IServiceProvider serviceProvider   ThisAddIn obj=new ThisAddIn(....,.....);      here i am confuse

Comment: I don't understand why you want use ThisAddIn object in your Winodws forms application?

Comment: because i want to perform operation on outlook any email attachment i want to process that email attachment in my application with c# code , when outlook open i am putting one button on top side name as "Download" when i select mail and click on download then releted attachment email process in c# code